# Can robovm convert every and all compiled jar file there is?

Tags: jar, converters, robovm, compiled, libs

Can robovm convert every and all compiled jar file there is or are there any exceptions?

Is there some code that utilizes something special that RoboVM just can't compile? I want to bring in some Apache libraries and I want to know if I can do that guaranteed not to run into any problems. Anyone know of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RoboVM uses the Android standard classes, so if it works on Android it 'should' work with RoboVM on iOS.

The only things that I can really think of that won't work are:

- Things that rely on OS specific behaviour, environments or system commands
- Things that alter bytecode (AOT compilation doesn't support this)

As far as apache libs. You'll obviously need to test, but I can't see why not.